# SHAREPOINT ERROR: value does not fall within expected range

Tags: sharepoint-designer, error, xslt-list-view-web-part, connected-web-parts

I am a newbie here,  need your help :-(

So here is my problem:

I have 2 Sharepoint servers A and B

Server  A using SQl server  2008 R2

Server B using SQL server 2005 SP4

Both using Sharepoint 2010 SP1

The idea is to copy server A to server B, because they are different SQl server I try to googling it and found the answer, and now Sharepoint at server A to copied to Server B. But I have a trouble, and two of my lists is getting error `value does not fall within expected range...`  when trying to make connection between both.

Please help me..  Any sugestions and help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you copy from server A to server B?  SQL Server 2008 R2 is the recommended database version for SharePoint 2010.  Beyond that I would think it a good idea to keep the versions the same.

Answer (score 1):

can u pls look into uls viewer for specific error. Its a general error. This error points to many reasons. e.g. "List View Lookup Threshold", "Column does not exist" etc.

Regards,

Dhaval

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the solution!

It's because column in list does not exist especially with `Lookup` columnt type. 
And then I ordering  import list using [powershell script](http://sharepointpsscripts.codeplex.com/) based on List Relation


Thanks for all..

Husnan

Comment: Can you Mark this then as answer?